# xsl inside for-each use different css class

Tags: css, xslt

how can I display the text inside a for-each loop, in xslt, using each time a different css class? can I generate somehow the name of the css class based on some variable or something?? is it possible? 
for example in the following code inside the foreach loop can I display the li with a different css class each time...such as in the first iteration li class="1"...second iteartion li class="2"...and obvious in css exists li.1{..}, li.2{...}

```
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
<xsl:variable name="newline">
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Collections of books</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:variable name="index" select="0"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="collection/book"> 
        <xsl:sort select="category"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lastCat" select="category"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::book[category=$lastCat])">
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>       
            <xsl:value-of select="category"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
                <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
                <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="isbn"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What? Can you be more specific? Maybe show an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You're XSLT is a little confusing as to whether you are outputting text or html. However, in answer to your immediate question you can easily add attributes to the exist **li** elements you are outputing in one of two ways.

Firstly, you can make use of the **xsl:attribute** statement, which should be added immediately following the **li** tag.

```
<li>
   <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
   </xsl:attribute>
   ...
```

The better method though is to use 'attribute value templates' to specify attributes. (The curly brackets indicate an AVT to be evaluated in this case, as opposed to being a piece of text to be literally output)

```
<li class="{position()}">
    ...
```

In both cases the output will be similar to the following

```
<li class="1">...
<li class="2">...
```

In this example I am simply using the **position()** to demonstrate how you can set attributes, but you could easily use variables if required.

```
<li class="{$classname}">
```